# How to make a resizable menu centered on the middle?

Tags: css, css-float, positioning

Pls help!!!

CSS:

```
body
{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body #header {

     width:100%;
     clear:both;
     height:90px;
     /*overflow:hidden*/;
     box-shadow: 1px 0px 10px 2px #000;
     } 

body #header #h_l {
   width: 30%;
  height: 90px;
background-image: linear-gradient(top, #e1e1e1 40%, #9d9d9d 99%);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #e1e1e1 40%, #9d9d9d 99%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #e1e1e1 40%, #9d9d9d 99%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #e1e1e1 40%, #9d9d9d 99%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #e1e1e1 40%, #9d9d9d 99%);

background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(40%, #e1e1e1), color-stop(99%, #9d9d9d)); /* Safari 4+, Chrome 2+ */  


 filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e1e1e1', endColorstr='#9d9d9d'); /* IE6 & IE7 */  
   -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#e1e1e1', endColorstr='#9d9d9d')"; /* IE8+ */  


background-image: -webkit-gradient(
    linear,
    left top,
    left bottom,
    color-stop(0.40, #e1e1e1),
    color-stop(0.99, #9d9d9d)
);
 float:left;
}

body #header #h_l #logo {

    float: right;
  /*-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; */
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ 
}

body #header #h_r {
   width: 70%;
  height: 90px;
background: #747474;

  float: right;
}

body #header #h_r #menu {

    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    float:left;
  /*-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; */
    max-width: 100%;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */ 
  }
```

HTML:

```
<body >

    <div id="header">

    <div id="h_l">

        <img id="logo"  title="logo" alt="logo" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/logo_plus100px_right.png" >
    </div>
    <div id="h_r">
        <span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Home_but.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Divider_1.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Solutions_but.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Divider_1.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Support_but.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Divider_1.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Company_but.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Divider_1.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Contact_but.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Divider_1.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Blog_but.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Divider_1.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Reseller_but.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Divider_1.png" ></span><span ><img id="menu" title="" alt="" src="{HTTP}{WEBSITE}/images/newlook/MM/Apps_but.png" ></span>
    </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Why do the elements from the menu on the right keep going on a new row one by one on browser window resizing?? How can i make it stop doing that and enable it to just resize like the image on the left, upon browser window resizing (as if the whole menu would be a full block)? Can it be done in CSS or do i need to make a javascript? Thanks to anyone who answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not easy to understand what you are trying to achieve here without the actual images. I have reproduced your case here:

http://jsfiddle.net/gVQ8x/1/

I've just set percentage width here (what's the `-ms-interpolation-mode` part for?):

```
body #header #h_r #menu {
    position: relative;
    left: -50px;
    float:left;
  /*-ms-interpolation-mode:bicubic; */
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 6%; /* was auto\9 */
}
```

I strongly advise you against using IE hacks. Try conditional classes instead: http://paulirish.com/2008/conditional-stylesheets-vs-css-hacks-answer-neither/

Another important issue that might cause problems in the future is that you have multiple elements in your document that share the same id, namely the aforementioned `body #header #h_r #menu`. The id must be unique if you want the javascript DOM manipulations to work properly and predictably.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I'll try to make the adjustments you suggested, and I'll reply upon success or failure.